# WSO2 4.6 identity server - obtaining a secure cookie

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 4.6 as an identity server. However, after authentication the samlssoTokenID cookie set in the browser is not secure. What are the possible options to do that ?? I am using JBoss as an application server and Apache HTTP as a webserver and using HTTPS.

Comment: AFAIK,  samlsoo cookie is set in to user's browser. Could you please explain the issue with that?

Comment: While examining the cookie using chrome's inspect element --> resources -->cookies, the samlsso cookie is not showing as secure as compared to the JSESSION ID which is secure.